# The redirect command is unexpected

Tags: io-redirection, command

Of course I know the function `strace` have a option `-o`,which can export the trace result into a local file.But I want to use the *redirect command*(>) here.

```
strace -e trace=file lastb|grep " = 0" >file
```

There is a logical problem here.The `>` follow the lastb.That is not my intention.Even I use a bracket cannot improve it like following:

```
(strace -e trace=file lastb)|grep " = 0" >file
```

So how to use the *redirect command*(>) to get a file contain the trace information?

Comment: Does `strace` not have a `-o filename` option for capturing trace output to `filename`?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes,I know,anyway thanks.But I want to use redirect command here.Is possible?

Comment: Let's get this clear. You are piping the output of strace through grep, and redirecting the output of grep to a file. But that's not what you want?
Are you using grep to select the trace information you want? Because if so, the first example would work OK. 
Or, are you trying to do that, but take a copy of the strace output into a file as well?

Comment: @BobEager I want to redirect the output of grep to a local file. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strace prints to `stderr`, not `stdout`. You will need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` if you want to pipe it.

`strace -e trace=file lastb 2>&1|grep " = 0" > file`

You can additionally suppress `lastb`'s normal output by redirecting it to `/dev/null` (shorthanded here as `&-`)

`strace -e trace=file lastb 2>&1 >&- | grep " = 0" file`

If you are just wanting to see where `lastb` is getting its information, that is typically in `/var/log/btmp`

Comment: I am confusing still.How do you find that is stderr but not a stdout?

Comment: It is noted in the manual page for strace. (`man strace`)